# The Effect of Tortoise Coordinates

Tags: black-holes, waves, potential, coordinate-systems

Referring particularly to

http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9909056

in regard to the wave equation for Schwarzschild-AdS black holes (p.4), I'm trying to understand tortoise coordinates.

So starting with the 4-dimensionalSchwarzschild-AdS metric in the general form

$$ds^2=-f(r )dt^2+\frac{dr^2}{f(r )}+r^2(d\theta^2+sin^2 \theta d\phi^2),$$

if I want to find the wave equation $\Box \phi=0$ in the Schrodinger-like form. This is done by introducing the separation of variables

$$\phi=\frac{\psi(r ) Y(\theta,\phi)e^{-i\omega t}}{r}$$

and then using the [tortoise coordinate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddington%E2%80%93Finkelstein_coordinates#Tortoise_coordinate) $dr_*=\frac{dr}{f(r )}$ to get

$$(\partial_{r_*}^2+\omega^2-V(r_*))\psi=0.$$

But I don't fully understand what this tortoise coordinate really does. In fact when I go through these calculations myself, I use the transformation

$$\psi'(r ) \to \frac{\psi'(r )}{f(r )}$$

and (fortunately) get the Schrodinger like form as in the paper above. However, they never explicitly state the potential and what I find is

$$V(r_*)=\frac{-\ell(\ell+1) f(r )+rf'(r )}{r^2}.$$

where $\ell$ is the angular momentum mode. **But note**, in my transformation, I never mentioned $r_*$ and hence why my $V(r_*)$ doesn't actually mention an $r_*$. This is where my confusion lies.

Is my potential right if I just replace the $r$ by $r_*$? i.e

$$V(r_*)=\frac{-\ell(\ell+1) f(r_* )+r_*f'(r_* )}{r_*^2}?$$

(I highly doubt it.) And if not, how do I recover $V(r )$ from here?

P.s. It would actually also be extremely helpful if someone knew $V(r )$, i.e. potential in original coordinates, for the Schwarzschild-AdS black hole.

Comment: You want to know the effect of the tortoise coordinate in this case and not in the simple case of a Schwarzschild metric, right? Just checking to make sure I understand.

Comment: @HDE226868 The Schwarzschild $AdS$ would certainly be the most helpful as it's the one I'm considering. What I'd really like to know is an explicit expression for both $V(r_+)$ and $V(r )$ and then maybe I'll be able to work from there. Right now the tortoise co-ordinate is confusing me.

Comment: Could anyone tell me why it's called the *tortoise* coordinate?

Comment: @Danu: The wiki page I've added to the text says it's due to Zeno's paradox involving Achilles racing a tortoise (Achilles cannot catch up to the tortoise (given a head start) b/c he always has to go half the distance); as such as $r\to2GM$, then the "tortoise" coodinate blows up (down?) to $-\infty$ (that is, someone approaching the Schwarszchild radius keeps getting further and further, I think, from the tortoise coordinate).

Comment: Tortoise coordinate is a simple nonlinear scale that embrace the Schwarzschild metric by putting, smoothly, schwarzschild radius in minus infinite. This transformation have a lot insights about physics of event horizon. The experience of the outside observers tells us that Schwarzschild radius is "asymptotically far away", in the sense that is intangible for then.

Comment: No, your potential necessarily has to be expressed in function of $r$, because there is not simple analytic function describing $r(r^*)$. See for instance, in the context of a standard Schwarzschild metrics (but applicable to your case with a function $f$), formulae $(14) \to (24)$ in this [paper](http://batteringram.org/science/gr/scalar_wave.pdf) [be careful, for the formula $(24)$, in this paper $f = 1 - 2m/r$, so this must be changed for the AdS case]

Answer (score 3):

The form of $V$ does not change. What you mean by $V(r_*)$ is $V(r(r_*))$ so you would've to explicitly find $r$ in terms of $r_*$ (which is impossible) to fully express your potential in terms of $r_*$.